# Debian Bookworm E: Unable to locate package

Tags: debian, apt, packages

I'm getting a lot of "E: Unable to locate package" errors when I try to install some popuplar packages...
in my /etc/apt/sources.list file I have these lines :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm contrib main non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates contrib main non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-proposed-updates contrib main non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-backports contrib main non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security contrib main non-free non-free-firmware
```

And the list of errors I'm getting :

```
E: Unable to locate package apt-clone
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
E: Unable to locate package cpp-8
E: Unable to locate package docker-buildx-plugin
E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'docker-ce-cli' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'docker-ce-rootless-extras' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package docker-compose-plugin
E: Package 'g++-8' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package gcc-8
E: Unable to locate package gcc-8-base:amd64
E: Unable to locate package golang-1.11
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'golang-1.11'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'golang-1.11'
E: Unable to locate package golang-1.11-doc
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'golang-1.11-doc'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'golang-1.11-doc'
E: Unable to locate package golang-1.11-go
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'golang-1.11-go'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'golang-1.11-go'
E: Unable to locate package golang-1.11-src
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'golang-1.11-src'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'golang-1.11-src'
E: Package 'mariadb-client-10.3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mariadb-client-core-10.3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mariadb-server-10.3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mariadb-server-core-10.3' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1'
E: Unable to locate package packages-microsoft-prod
E: Unable to locate package perl-modules-5.28
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'perl-modules-5.28'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'perl-modules-5.28'
E: Unable to locate package php-symfony-debug
E: Package 'php7.4' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-bcmath
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-bcmath'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-bcmath'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-bz2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-bz2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-bz2'
E: Package 'php7.4-cli' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php7.4-common' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-curl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-curl'
E: Package 'php7.4-fpm' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-gd'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-imagick
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-imagick'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-imagick'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-intl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-intl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-intl'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-json
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-json'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-json'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-mbstring
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-mbstring'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-mbstring'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-mysql'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-mysql'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-opcache
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-opcache'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-opcache'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-readline
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-readline'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-readline'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-soap
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-soap'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-soap'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-sqlite3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-sqlite3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-sqlite3'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-sqlite3-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-sqlite3-dbgsym'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-sqlite3-dbgsym'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-xml
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-xml'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-xml'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-xmlrpc
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-xmlrpc'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-xmlrpc'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-zip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-zip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-zip'
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-16
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-16
E: Package 'python' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-meld3
E: Package 'python-minimal' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-pkg-resources' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python2' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python2-minimal
E: Unable to locate package python2.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python2.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.7'
E: Unable to locate package python2.7-minimal
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python2.7-minimal'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.7-minimal'
E: Package 'python3.7' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python3.7-minimal
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7-minimal'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7-minimal'
E: Unable to locate package webmin
```

I precise I executed the commands `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`

Precisions : It's a fresh VPS with Debian 12 installed in it, the VPS is located in Germany and pings works well. I use ssh to send commands.

This is the output of `apt-get update` command :

```
root@vmi1567361:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-proposed-updates InRelease [59.5 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports InRelease [56.5 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages.diff/Index [63.3 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2023-12-28-0205.20-F-2023-12-28-0205.20.pdiff [296 B]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages T-2023-12-28-0205.20-F-2023-12-28-0205.20.pdiff [296 B]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [132 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main Translation-en [78.5 kB]
Fetched 490 kB in 1s (413 kB/s)                                  
Reading package lists... Done
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: I've checked a handful of those packages and can confirm none of them exist in the apt sources you have set up - note: I haven't checked EVERY package mentioned in the error

Comment: Did you actually check that `apt-get update` worked correctly without error? Were you able to see its output? Can you provide this output?

Comment: @A.B I added the apt-get update output to the post

Answer (score 1):

What is failing here is a simple retrieval by http. However you have not offered any evidence to suggest that you have attempted to investigate the issue at all. Nor have you provided any details of where this machine is located, how you are accessing it or how it access the internet. Nor have you provided any history of the machine and the specific task at hand. Did you build it? Did it work previously? Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. And from what you have presented here we can only assume (and hope) this is not the case here.

Meanwhile you might consider checking if the host can resolve DNS entries. You can do this from the shell with the `host` command, e.g.:

```
$ host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 142.250.187.196
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4009:81f::2004
```

It is possible that apt has been configured to use a proxy which is no longer accepting requests from the host:

```
$ sudo find /etc/apt -type f -exec grep -H -i proxy {} \;
```

It needs an IP address and a route to connect to the target, the commands to show these are `ip a` and `ip route`.

The gateway device must be running and accepting your traffic.

You need to ensure that your firewall policy is not blocking access - `iptables -L` *may* show something relevant.

Comment: First, thank you for your contribution. The server is a fresh VPS with Debian 12 installed on it, it's located in Germany and I'm connected to it with SSH. I tried the commands you written, the server is able to resolve www.google.com and it doesn't seem to have any proxy and iptables package isn't installed in it. Screenshot of command results here: https://share.cleanshot.com/hGrqhJZd

Comment: try to install it again and this time, from a trustworthy installation medium

Answer (score 1):

*bookworm* is Debian 12. All package displayed as not found are not part of Debian 12:

- [`apt-clone`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apt-clone)

  Debian 10 or trixie/sid, (future Debian 13), not Debian 12.
- `cpp-8`, `gcc-8`

  [Debian 10](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/gcc-8)
- `containerd.io`, `docker-buildx-plugin`, `docker-ce`, `docker-ce-cli`

  Upstream Docker, not from Debian 12 repositories
- `golang-1.11`

  Debian 10
- ...

  Etc. etc.

None of these packages are provided by Debian 12, but Debian 12 is the only source configured.

So there is no Debian system error. The mistake is from trying to install unavailable packages.

I guess this was intended for Debian 10 augmented with upstream Docker.